Using Stripe payment gateway in .NET MAUI application with Windows target platform
I want to use Stripe payment gateway in my maui app. The problem is that Stripe needs to redirect the client to a specific page: if operation is successful, so client is redirected to success page, same for failure. So, I am not sure if it is possible to implement such kind of stuff in my app because it doesn't have pages. I am attaching stripe connection options here:
 var options = new SessionCreateOptions
 {
     // Stripe calls the URLs below when certain checkout events happen such as success and failure.
     SuccessUrl = $"{thisApiUrl}/checkout/success?sessionId=" + "{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}", // Customer paid.
     CancelUrl = s_wasmClientURL + "failed",  // Checkout cancelled.
     PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string> // Only card available in test mode?
     {
         "card"
     },
     LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
     {
         new()
         {
             PriceData = new SessionLineItemPriceDataOptions
             {
                 UnitAmount = (long)product.Price, // Price is in USD cents.
                 Currency = "USD",
                 ProductData = new SessionLineItemPriceDataProductDataOptions
                 {
                     Name = product.BaseRequestId.ToString(),
                 },
             },
             Quantity = 1,
         },
     },
     Mode = "payment" // One-time payment. Stripe supports recurring 'subscription' payments.
 };

The problem happens when I come here: (CheckoutController.cs)
var service = new SessionService();
 var session = await service.CreateAsync(options); //error

HTTP request has been sent from ReadyOrders.xaml.cs:
response = await HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("https://localhost:44368/api/Checkout", order);
//var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); //Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).

I want to know if it is possible to add stripe in a maui app which target platform is Windows. The main problem is being redirected to success and failure pages. Maybe it is possible to implement payment without them? I haven't found any examples of using Stripe in mobile or desktop apps.

Stripe Checkout does currently require a success_url to successfully create a session. If it is possible for you to host a webpage at all, it may be sufficient to simply send your users to a page that says something like "your payment was successful, please return to the app"
If Stripe's PaymentLinks would fit your usecase, they do support staying on the same page when their Checkout Session finishes[1]. If you are largely selling the same item or set of items and don't have a dynamic cart, this may be a viable option for you.
Stripe does have Android and iOS SDKs [2, 3]. When looking in to this, I found a user mentioning that they created an iOS binding library around stripe-ios[4]. There is also a third party GH repo that seems to be for bindings of Stripe's SDKs[5]. So binding libraries may also be an option that is viable for you.
Stripe's other payment offerings involve hosting your own webpage, but for you that may also run in to the same constraint of not being able to host a webpage.
[1] https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_links/payment_links/object#payment_link_object-after_completion
[2] https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios
[3] https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android
[4] .NET MAUI ApplePay, GooglePay + Stripe
[5] https://github.com/TheEightBot/Stripe.MAUI

Thanks for your answer, @Pompey. Do you think it is possible to use these libraries when I am running my app on Windows machine?

I mean, not on Android or IOS emulator.
